# Lost Focus problems

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I use the LostFocus Event in vb.net to check the validity of a field for the name.
After this field a have another one which is the for the password validity, and i'm handilg the same event in order to check the password.
My problem comes when i run the (name) lost focus, runs the code inside the sub and after that automatically goes to the password_lostfocus which brings me alot of troubles.
That happens even i use the error provider which works fine and bring to me the error with the red flashing.After that i put the command (name_textbox.focus), which logically has to bring the control in the name_textbox.. But NO.. the control goes to the Password_textbox sub automatically. 
Please see my sub

```
Private Sub UsernameTextBox_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UsernameTextBox.LostFocus
    Select Case DB_Access.IfExistUser(UsernameTextBox.Text, sender, e)
        Case True
            PasswordTextBox.Focus()
        Case False
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(UsernameTextBox, "Ο χρήστης ΔΕΝ υπάρχει παρακαλώ καλέστε τον Administrator")
            Beep()
            UsernameTextBox.Text = ""
            UsernameTextBox.Focus()
    End Select

End Sub
```

Please if anyone have seen this issue and face it, assist me.
Excuse me for some Greek characters they are meaningless, they are comments

Comment: Please don't clear the username text if the name exists. If JeffO were taken in your system, I'd like the ease of just adding a 1 to make it: JeffO1 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Well finally i found that.
In order to handle the Login Form as it give it from visual studio 2010 you need to do it in only one sub (Lost Focus) and that is only the password_LostFocus.
I believe the particular form is meant to be like that.
Any way i solve the issue and if anybody needs assistance on that just "asc a question"

Comment: You might consider using the Leave event instead of LostFocus, so it won't fire if the program loses focus.